# Why my distribution certificate is revoked?

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store

I got this mail:
[image]

Why my distribution certificate is revoked?
Tnx:).

Answer (score 1):

This can happen sometimes when you try to run your app in Xcode and a popup comes up and asks if you would like to "Revoke and Request" a valid signing certificate.

This is not an issue as you can go get another one, or use the updated existing one. It is not something to worry about.

Comment: thanks for feedback. Last time when i run the app was in 03/01/2015.